# What should be the right practice to handle duplicate linq queries to Database?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

What should be the right practice to handle duplicate linq queries to Database?
By duplicate queries, I mean such queries that recurs in my code.

Example:

I notice that in my code recurs following query:

```
dataContext.Users.Where(u =>u.IsActive && u.IsAdmin).OrderByDescent(u => u.Name)
```

Where should I place the method that contains above query. Should it be `UserRepository`(in this manner, I will probably end with god class which is bad practice)? or should I create class architecture to handle this.

I wonder what are your thoughts about this. And what class structure in your opinion will be most generic and vulnerable to reuse.

I have in mind that, I can use a store procedure as a place for recurring queries, but I don't want to go that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it **can** be in the `UserRepository`, but you can also build up an `Godclass` for standardized queries (Create, Delete, and so on) and take use of an `Service Layer` or `Extensions` to Filter the results from `GetAll()` Method in the `UserRepository`.

**Update**
I'm trying to show it a little bit more detailed.

1. Build an generic repository that holds all your statements to retrieve/store your data.
2. Create an service layer that consume from/send to the repository.
3. Add extension methods to filter for specific results. (featured with c# 3.0)

Some code:

```
// Repository (non-generic)
private IQueryable<User> GetUser()
{
  var results = from u in _db.Users
                select new User
                {
                  ID = u.ID,
                  Username = u.Username,
                  // and so on
                };

  return results;
}


//Service Layer  
private User GetUser(string Username)
{
   User u = _repository.GetUser().WithUsername(username)
                                 .SingleOrDefault();
} 

// Extension Method
public static IQueryable<User> WithUsername(this IQueryable<User> qry, string username)
{
  return from u in qry
         where u.Username == username
         select u;
}
```

This approach is related to Rob Conerys MVC StoreFront Preview. The implementation maybe vary in other projects, but this is one way to do it.

Comment: Sorry I don't exactly understand what you mean. Filtering a results from GetAll() method should be good solution. But how to organize classes to do it rightly?

Comment: add some code example, that maybe animate your fantasy.

Comment: On the first sight it is very good. I will review the code more detailed in the evening. Thank you for that. Do you have in mind some other solutions?